# Admin module not working after sample

Tags: magento

Following the following steps, I still don't see it working:

http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers

Is this still applicacple for the latest version of Magento, or is that tutorial outdated?

Is there anything else that could cause the 404 error to come up?

config file:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld</module>
                <frontName>adminhelloworld</frontName>
            </args>
        </the_name_of_this_element_is_not_important_it_should_be_unique>
    </routers>
</admin>
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <tutorial_menu translate="title" module="adminhelloworld">
            <title>Tutorial Menu</title> 
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <children>
                <first_page module="adminhelloworld">
                    <title>Our First Page</title> 
                    <action>adminhelloworld/index/index</action>
                </first_page>
            </children>
        </tutorial_menu>
        <system>
            <children>
                <another_menu_from_us>
                    <title>Here Too!</title> 
                    <action>adminhelloworld/index/index</action>
                </another_menu_from_us>
            </children>
        </system>
    </menu> 
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <helpers>
        <adminhelloworld>
            <class>Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_Helper</class>
        </adminhelloworld>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Index controller:

class Alanstormdotcom_Adminhelloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

```
    //create a text block with the name of "example-block"
    $block = $this->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
    ->setText('<h1>This is a text block</h1>');

    $this->_addContent($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
```

}
   protected function _addContent(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
   {
       $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
       return $this;
   }
}

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Magento Administration, belongs to http://magento.stackexchange.com

Comment: this is module development, and has nothing to do with Administration

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work...

There was some missing open php tags in the code samples, but the most important part was clearing all the right caches, and then the right things started showing up!

Always remember the cache part!

Hope this helps someone